# error test junit timestamp java format json

Tags: java, junit

I am currently having a problem on a date test and I do not see how to get out of it I looked for a long time but nothing to do if someone could help me thank you in advance

```
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(now);
        Country country = new Country("France", timestamp);

        given(countryService.getDetail(anyString())).willReturn(country);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/country/France"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("country").value("France"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("lastUpdate").value(timestamp));
```

java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "lastUpdate"
Expected :2021-04-29T15:05:09.090235
Actual   :2021-04-29T13:05:09.090+00:00

Comment: The problem is that the "Expected" value (timestamp) doesn't match with the actually value ("lastUpdate"), in particular i see the they different when it comes to millisecond. Bear in mind what is assertion validates is the value returned by Timestamp.toString(), and the format is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff". I suggest that you apply a format first which matches the one of lastUpdate and then apply the assertion. You can also cut the milliseconds which are useless in the context.